# eclipse share common index

Tags: eclipse, magento, dltk

Is there a way to have an eclipse project use a common index? So far, I have a dozen Magento repositories that all pretty much have the same code base, but are separate projects and separate Magento web sites for separate clients. There are literally tens of thousands of files in each Magento project. I keep all these projects in the same eclipse workspace. Most of the time I have all the projects closed except for the one I am currently working on. The reason for this is because if I have more than one project open, DLTK indexing will pretty much bring my Mac to a crawl and eclipse will stop responding. Although not ideal, this works.

I would like to have eclipse NOT index the current project but to use a source code base that I specify. I would like to be able to say for THIS project, have eclipse do look ups in a code base elsewhere on my computer (i.e. do lookups in /Users/davidt/Documents/projects/magento...) that DLTK has already indexed and has NOT changed in any way (so DLTK indexing won't scan it and slow down my computer). This way I can have all the autocompletion, definition lookups, refactoring and other modern IDE conveniences without having DLTK indexing slow down my computer to a crawl. Is this possible in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup the Magento codebase as a PHP libraray.

[image]

Then, when you're creating your project, make sure you select the Magento library.

[image]